# Spring lookup-method and abstract class

Tags: java, spring

Would like to understand how Spring creates a bean from an abstract class, as if it is instantiating an Abstract class, as it is known that is not possible. Would like to know, what is getting instantiated for the "abstractLookupBean" bean.

Thank you.

```
public abstract class AbstractLookupDemoBean implements DemoBean {

    public abstract MyHelper getMyHelper();

    public void someOperation() {
        getMyHelper().doSomethingHelpful();
    }
}
```

DemoBean class

```
public interface DemoBean {
    public MyHelper getMyHelper();

    public void someOperation();
}
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"    
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans       
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd">

    <bean id="helper" class="com.rami.methodlookup.helper.MyHelper" scope="prototype"/>     

    <bean id="abstractLookupBean" class="com.rami.methodlookup.helper.AbstractLookupDemoBean">         
        <lookup-method name="getMyHelper" bean="helper"/>     
    </bean>   

    <bean id="standardLookupBean" class="com.rami.methodlookup.helper.StandardLookupDemoBean">         
        <property name="myHelper">             
            <ref local="helper"/>         
        </property>     
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

main class

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    GenericXmlApplicationContext ctx = null; 
    try{
        ctx = new GenericXmlApplicationContext();
        ctx.load("applicationContext.xml");
        ctx.refresh();
        DemoBean abstractBean = (DemoBean) ctx.getBean("abstractLookupBean"); //What is getting instantiated?
    }finally{
        ctx.close();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see spring documentation [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection)

> ...If the method is abstract, the dynamically-generated subclass will implement the method. Otherwise, the dynamically-generated subclass will override the concrete method defined in the original class...