# Creating abstract object in Spring - Lookup Method

Tags: java, spring

I've came across this article [ARTICLE](http://www.javarticles.com/2015/05/spring-lookup-method-example.html) when I was looking for information about LookUp methods in Spring. I can't understand one thing which isn't explained there. If we got a class:

```
public abstract class PizzaShop {
public abstract Pizza makePizza();
public abstract Pizza makeVeggiePizza();
}
```

and Spring Container:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

(...)

<bean id="pizzaShop" class="com.javarticles.spring.PizzaShop">
    <lookup-method name="makePizza" bean="pizza"/>
    <lookup-method name="makeVeggiePizza" bean="veggiePizza"/>
</bean>

<bean id="pizza" class="com.javarticles.spring.Pizza" scope="prototype"/>

<bean id="veggiePizza" class="com.javarticles.spring.Pizza" scope="prototype">
    <property name="isVeg" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Which has a bean which is created basing on abstract class!
And now when we perform such code in main method:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "applicationContext.xml");
PizzaShop pizzaShop = (PizzaShop) context.getBean("pizzaShop");
```

We are creating an abstract object! Which apart framework isn't allowed. Why is it possible here, or where i'm making mistake in understanding whole concept?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27894740/spring-lookup-method-and-abstract-class

Comment: Well, maybe you need to know about libraries like [cglib](https://github.com/cglib/cglib) and [javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/)

Comment: Does this abstract class (containing the @lookup abstract method) need to be in the component scanning path?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible because the Spring Framework manipulates bytecode at runtime to create a subclass of the bean class that defines at least one of these properties with  `lookup-method`.
Here is [Spring 5 Lookup method injection documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.x/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lookup-method-injection).

> **Lookup method injection**
>
> Lookup method injection is the ability of the container to override
>   methods on container managed beans, to return the lookup result for
>   another named bean in the container. The lookup typically involves a
>   prototype bean as in the scenario described in the preceding section.
>   **The Spring Framework implements this method injection by using
>   bytecode generation from the CGLIB library to generate dynamically a
>   subclass that overrides the method.**

Whatever the method be abstract or not, Spring relies on the same mechanism : a dynamically generated subclass.
In the first case, it implements.
In the second case, it overrides.

> If the method is abstract, the dynamically-generated subclass
>   implements the method. Otherwise, the dynamically-generated subclass
>   overrides the concrete method defined in the original class.